# Ignoring return value of 'scanf', declared with attribute warn_unused_result

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

So I am somewhat confused on why I am getting theses errors when I try compiling this program. What I am trying to do is read in binary matrices from an input file and then do matrix multiplication. But i receive this error:

```
error: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared 
with attribute warn_unused_result [-Werror=unused-result]        
   24 |     scanf("%d %d", &arows, &acolumns);

void read_matrices() {
    //this will read in what is inside the binary file and create the desired matrices

    //this will make the size of the matrix
    scanf("%d %d", &arows, &acolumns);

    //this will take in the elements for the first matrix
    for (i = 0; i < arows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < acolumns; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //this will make the size of the second matrix
    scanf("%d %d", &arows, &bcolumns);

    //this will take in the elements for the second matrix
    for (i = 0; i < brows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < bcolumns; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d ", &matrix2[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("using read matrices function\n");
}
void mult_matrices() {

   // Multiplying first and second matrices and storing it in result
   for (i = 0; i < arows; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j < bcolumns; ++j) {
         for (k = 0; k < brows; ++k) {
            results[i][j] += matrix[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
         }
      }
   }
    printf("using multiply matrices function\n");
}
void show_matrices() {
    //this will show the new matrices after multiplying 
    //this is where we will also sort each row in ascending order
    for ( i = 0; i < r_rows; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < r_columns; j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ", results[i][j]);
            if (j == r_columns - 1)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    printf("using show matrices function\n");

}
```

also these variables are global since we were forced to make functions not take in anything like

```
int main() 
{
    // initialize any global variables

    read_matrices();
    mult_matrices();
    show_matrices();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, it is an overagressive warning.  You can turn off the warning, or you can check the result:

```
    if( scanf("%d %d", &arows, &acolumns) != 2 )
        return;
```

or you can throw it away:

```
    (void) scanf("%d %d", &arows, &acolumns);
```

Comment: thanks that worked and stopped the over-aggressive warnings.